# Can I delete a file when I am watching it with a FileSystemWatcher?

Tags: c#, filesystemwatcher

We know that in .NET (C# to be specific), we can use a `FileSystemWatcher` to detect any type of modification.

```
public void MessageFileWatcher(string Path, string FileName)
        {
            FileSystemWatcher Watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
            Watcher.Path = Path;
            Watcher.Filter = FileName;
            Watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite;
            Watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
            Watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        }
```

but I want to keep a watch on a file and after some time also want to delete that file.

To be precise. can `FileSystemWatcher` class always look for modifications... and if I want to delete that particular file, will it raise an exception?

Comment: Try it and find out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It won't raise an exception.

A `FileSystemWatcher` doesn't watch files: it watches the file system. In this case you'll find that there will be at least the Deleted event raised when the file is removed.

Answer (score 0):

A `FileSystemWatcher` wathes a path with an optional filter, not a single file. Of course, if you set the filter to be the name of the file, the watcher will only watch one file, but that is more of a side-effect that its intended usage.

That said, it's clear that **yes**, you can delete the file you are watching. However, the deletion should not raise the `Changed` event. To monitor the deletion you will need to use the [`Deleted`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.deleted.aspx) event.